# bash: How can I use find to check for backup file and delete (if exists)?

Tags: bash, find, xargs, rm

I have an onsite backup folder /backup/ that has an offsite rsynced copy mounted locally as /mnt/offsite/backup/. My onsite backup drive is getting full, so I'd like to delete files older than 365 days, but first check to see if that file exists offsite, and log to file the filenames that were removed (to exclude from rsync).

I've come close with this:

```
cd /mnt/offsite/backup && find . -type f -mtime +365 -exec rm /backup/{} \; | >> file.lst
```

However the redirection isn't working. I've tried placing the >> in different places, and can't get it to work with exec in there. I've also tried using xargs rm, and can get the redirect working, but can't get xargs to delete from the second path:

```
cd /mnt/offsite/backup && find . -type f -mtime +365 >> file.lst | xargs rm /backup/
```

What's the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
find /mnt/offsite/backup -type f -mtime +365 -exec rm {} \; -print >> file.lst
```